# Tabulator : Bad rendering when coupling between Frozen & headerFilter in a column

Tags: javascript, tabulator

When i use a simple headerFilter in a column that i wish to be frozen also, the tab header is not taking in consideration in height of the filter box.

Please refere to the Fiddle below which is the standard Tabulator example with the two options added.
https://jsfiddle.net/Ergo0ne/72Lrqa8y/8/

I've tried to change the height of the tab header but it's not working. Feel free to give it a shot :)

Thanks.

Html

```
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

the tab header is not taking in consideration the height of the filter box in 1st column

JS / JQuery / Tabulator

```
`$("#example-table").tabulator({
    height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
    layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
    columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150, headerFilter:"input", headerFilterPlaceholder:"My filter", frozen:true},
        {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress", width:250},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col", width:250},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center", width:250},
    ],
});

//define some sample data
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
];

//load sample data into the table
$("#example-table").tabulator("setData", tabledata);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known issue with version 3.x and has now been fixed in the 4.0 release, try updating your Tabulator source files and you should be sorted